# Retrieving`HasMany` Entities in a single query - Fluent-NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an `Entity` which holds a collection of `OtherEntity` in a many-to-many style relationship. The mapping for this property looks like:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.OtherEntity)
                .AsBag()
                .Table("EntityToOtherEntityMapping")
                .ParentKeyColumn("EntityId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("OtherEntityId")
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.None();
```

I notice that when retrieving a collection of `Entity`'s there's a seperate SQL query for each collection of `OtherEntity`.

How can I have Fluent-NHibernate execute this retrieval in one query rather than n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be in setting the FetchModel to Eager and selecting a ResultTransformer:

```
.SetFetchMode("Tags", FetchMode.Eager)
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add fetch join on your property.

```
.Fetch.Join();
```